# Barring legal fees — why does one lone junior barrister (for each party) appear, in a minority of some UK Supreme Court cases?

Tags: uk-supreme-court

In most UKSC cases, at least 1 QC and 1 junior barrister appear for each party to the case. Often, multiple QC's and multiple juniors appear. But I have stumbled on exceptions like

- [*Mathieson v SSWP*  [2015] UKSC 47](https://www.bailii.org/uk/cases/UKSC/2015/47.html), where Respondent was represented by merely a junior barrister. But [he, Tim Buley,](https://www.landmarkchambers.co.uk/people/tim-buley-qc/) became QC in 2019.
- [*Her Majesty's Attorney General v Crosland* [2021] UKSC 15 (10 May 2021)](http://www.bailii.org/uk/cases/UKSC/2021/15.html), where each litigant is represented by merely a junior barrister. [Nate Eldredge sussed out that the Applicant's barrister became QC in 2022](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/82658/barring-legal-fees-why-does-one-lone-junior-barrister-for-each-party-appear#comment180070_82658).
- **Just edit this post, if you know of other such UKSC cases.**

***Rule out legal costs and fees as a reason.*** Obviously, SSWP and Her Majesty’s Attorney General are wealthy enough to instruct QC's.

And these cases can't simply be easier! If a case were straightforward, it would never have been litigated or appealed up to the UKSC, or been permitted by the UKSC to appeal!

Comment: Just a guess, but it may be a right of passage en route from being a junior barrister to a QC, in much the way that at some point, every young  barrister does their first big stakes jury trial as a first chair lawyer, and might be reserved for junior barristers just on the brink of being trusted enough to make that transition.

Comment: Indeed, the barrister in this case was appointed QC just a few months later: https://www.5rb.com/news/5rb-congratulates-aidan-eardley-on-his-appointment-as-queens-counsel/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer is that, despite the wording in the question, this case is simply easier. Note that the Attorney General is listed as the applicant, rather than the appellant.

The case is a straightforward action for contempt of court but since the court in question is the Supreme Court, it heard the case itself (although with a different set of judges).

Comment: This case seems to be *particularly* straightforward.  The contempt charge is for publishing a court decision early, while it was still under embargo.  The defendant posted the document on Twitter with a statement that he had deliberately chosen to violate the embargo and knew that it constituted contempt of court.  His only defense was to claim that his actions were justified by the severity of climate change, but the law does not allow for any justification defense for contempt.  A pretty classic "smoking gun".

Comment: Does my edit change your answer?